# Shared Subscription with Spring Integration Mqttv5 not Receiving Messages

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-mqtt

I have a spring boot (v. 3.0.5) project using spring-integration-mqtt (v. 6.0.4) and also use paho mqttv5 client. I want to setup a shared subscription via the `ClientManager` and the Integration DSL. But I cannot get it to work.

```kotlin
@Bean
fun clientManager(): ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions> {
    val connectionOptions = MqttConnectionOptions()
    connectionOptions.serverURIs = arrayOf("tcp://example.org:1883")
    
    val clientManager = Mqttv5ClientManager(connectionOptions, "testClient")
    clientManager.setPersistence(MqttDefaultFilePersistence())
    return clientManager
}

@Bean
fun mqttTestInFlow(clientManager: ClientManager<IMqttAsyncClient, MqttConnectionOptions>): IntegrationFlow {
    val messageProducer = Mqttv5PahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter(
        clientManager,
        "\$share/testGroup/foo/test",
    )

    return IntegrationFlow.from(messageProducer)
        .channel("mqttInputChannel")
        .get()
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
fun handler(message: Message<String>) {
    println("Received message: ${message.payload}")
}
```

I can see in the logs from my mosquitto broker that the subscription is created and also that messages published to `foo/test` are published to the `testClient` (the spring service). But my handler never receives these messages.
When I remove the `$share/testGroup` from the topic string then everything works just fine.

Comment: And what is that `$share/testGroup`? Why do we need it?

Comment: I want to subscribe to a shared subscription as specified here https://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/os/mqtt-v5.0-os.html#_Toc3901250

Comment: Yeah... It looks like this feature doesn't work well with Paho client: https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/367. Thank you for sharing! We may try to investigate it more and find some workaround

Comment: Here is more in this blog post: https://yogin16.github.io/2017/07/15/mqtt-shared-sub-with-paho/

Comment: Thank you for your help. We will try to work without shared subscriptions for now. But may come back to this at some point.